# How to check if a file is empty via ajax call in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to check if a file exists or not via Ajax call in php.

In php file:

```
$filename1 = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
```

The above line gives an error when the user does not upload the image. But the code is working fine if user does submit the image.

So I did some code to check whether I am receiving the file or not in php:

```
if (empty($_FILES)) {
  echo 'Image is required.';
}else{
 echo "Image is receiving.";
}
```

The above code is not working, and the below line shows the error when the user did not submit the image:

```
Undefined index: photo
```

Kindly suggest how to check if the image exists or not.
Any ideas or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: share your HTML.did you name your input photo?

Comment: is your form `multipart/form-data`?

Answer (score 0):

use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function in php

eg:

```
if (isset($_FILES['photo'])) {
  //do the process
} else {
  // echo error
}
```

Comment: In this case, I think `empty()` is a better choice. `isset()` only checks if the variable is defined and isn't null. If `$_FILES['photo']` is an empty array, this would still return true, while `empty()` would return false.

Answer (score 0):

Try below section

```
if (isset($_FILES['photo']['name']) && $_FILES['photo']['name']!='') {
 // Value Exist
} else {
  // Empty value
}
```

Comment: Instead of two conditions, you can simply do: `empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])`.

Comment: if you check the empty value condition without "isset"  it's return the warning error.
"empty" check values exist or not.
"Isset" check the particular variable exist (set) or not.

Comment: `isset()` checks if a variable is set and isn't null. `empty()` returns true if the variable isn't set, is null, is an empty string, is zero, is an empty array or any other value that is considered "empty" (read the manual for more info about that). It does not throw warnings on undefined variables/array indexes. So you never to use `isset()` when using `empty()`